# How to access to a specific init block in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a kotlin class with two initialization blocks. My constructor contains two parameters one of type list of String and another of boolean type which can be null.

I wish if I create an instance of my class with a single parameter (list of String) I can only execute the first initialization block and if I create an instance with the two parameters I can execute the second initialization block

```
class User(val type1: List<String>, val type2: Boolean?) {
    init {
        println("First initializer block executed ")
    }
    
    init {
        println("Second initializer block executed ")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val list1: List<String> = listOf("One", "Two", "Three")
    val user1 = User(list1,false)
}
```

how can i do it please ?

Comment: you can add default value in the fun like this User(val type1: List<String>, val type2: Boolean? = false)

Comment: hi @ahmadbajwa i add default value to false but when i call val user1 = User(list1,true) the two blocs are executed

Comment: you can call first like this val user1 = User(list1) and second like this val user2 = User(list1,true)

Comment: sorry my bad now I understand its not the fun you want its init{}

Comment: why your using init for separation you can use if else with bool.

Comment: yes i can use if else also

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have 2 inits. Just make a single init with logic inside to determine what to do. Like this for example:

```
class User(val type1: List<String>, val type2: Boolean? = null) {
    init {
        if (type2 == null) {
            println("First initializer block executed ")
        } else {
            println("Second initializer block executed ")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ivo, i tes your code and i have a kotlin error : class User(val type1: List<String>, val type2: Boolean? = null) {
    init {
        if (type2 == null) {
            println("First initializer block executed ")
        } else {
            println("Second initializer block executed ")
        }
    }
}fun main() {
    val list1: List<String> = listOf("Marc", "Julie", "Eric")
    val user = User(list1) 
}, i have error: expecting member declaration
    if (type2 == true) {

Comment: @ln3106 what error? it works fine for me

Comment: sorry, @Ivo, it's work fine.